# Why is Firebase saving data with unique id's?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, papaparse

I am just wondering why my data is being saved into Firebase with unique id's?

Here is my code I am using Papa Parse to parse CSV data to an array:

```
var rootRef = new Firebase('https://xxx.firebaseio.com/inventory');
    var myRows = [];
    Papa.parse("https://xxx.co.uk/xxx.csv", {
      download: true,
        step: function(row) {
          myRows.set(row.data);
        },
        complete: function() {
          console.log(myRows);
          var newMessageRef = rootRef.set();
          newMessageRef.set(myRows);
        }
    });
```

I'm having trouble understanding why my data is being saved with a unique id instead of being set to one static name each time?

I am just trying to save the data inside an array or object named `vehicles`. Any help would be great.

Comment: What does the `console.log(myRows)` print?

Comment: Help with what issue exactly name vs. ID?

Comment: You are doing rootRef.set(), with no parameters. Doesn't that cause an error?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not valid in Javascript. There is no set method for array, nor is it valid to do set with no values on a Firebase object. With a valid code you save the object in the location specified in the Firebase constructor, overwriting the data there. Firebase doesn't store arrays, only object trees. When you write an array, the items inside use their index as the key in the object it saves.